# How to create a custom NSMenuItem

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

Well, I have quite a basic question which I can't seem to find an answer to. I followed this guide to create a StatusBar menu, which works great... 
However, I would like to add a custom NSMenuItem containing custom stuff. As example such as the sound slider, or the switch user account row ect.

How can I do that?

Even links to tutorials are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases, you'll create a custom view containing the slider or whatever else you want to appear in the menu item. Then you call `setView:` on the `NSMenuItem` in question.

For more details, check this article from Apple's documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/ViewsInMenuItems.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `setView:` method of `NSMenuItem`.

Comment: Hi, is it possible that you can show an example as well? This is more of a helpful comment to the question than an actual answer. Thank you! :)